# Keyboard with only number and letters input for username field?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a textfield and I would like to remove the punctuation marks from the keyboard and also the spacebar. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot remove anything from the keyboard without providing your own custom keyboard. You may however, intercept characters before they appear in the textfield using it's delegate method `-(BOOL)textField: shouldChangeCharactersInRange: replacementString:`. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)